# Can we make in query on firebase like sql in query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "lambeosaurus": {
    "height" : 2.1,
    "length" : 12.5,
    "weight": 5000
  },
  "stegosaurus": {
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 2500
  }
  "pegosaurus": {
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "weight" : 1000
  }
}
```

I want to select stegosaurus and pegosaurus from my parent node. It is similar like in query where we provide comma separated values in the query. e.g 
`select * from my_table where id in ('stegosaurus','pegosaurus');`

I have read the documentation of firebase and no help. Any suggestion will be very helpfull.

Comment: Possible duplicated: [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: Did you check the answer??

Comment: Yes. I have tried these solutions but nothing work. So I paginated the call and check that my values exist. We have to request again and again with a key in equalto param so this was also not suitable for me. There is no method provided by firebase in which we can do in the query as SQL because all the data in firebase is stored in JSON.

Comment: @aqiltariq65 yes the solution that I gave you is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

You can only do the following:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");

ref.orderByKey().equalTo("pegosaurus").on("value", (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=> {
     let length = childSnapshot.val().length;
     let height=childSnapshot.val().height;
     let weight=childSnapshot.val().weight;
    });
});
```

Here you check if the key is equal to `pegosaurus` and then you loop and retrieve the children data.